# Update query Error Code: 1062 Duplicate entry '718-1-1' for key 'UK_Product'

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run my query:

```
UPDATE Product
SET IdProduct = 1 
WHERE IdProduct = 10
```

I recieve the following error:

`Error Code: 1062 Duplicate entry '718-1-1' for key 'UK_Product'`

Can someone please help me avoid it?

Comment: You are trying to insert a duplicate record in a primary key column. I gues IdProduct is your primary key, and the value 1 already exists for the same.

Comment: you have a composite key over 3 felds. please post the output from : SHOW CREATE TABLE UK_Product; then i can say which key it is

Comment: @I_am_Batman - it can be every unique key give this error.